# How do I test my double-click prevention?

Tags: testing, double-click

I have seen many articles on [how to prevent double-clicks](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/07/jquery-double-submission) (linked to the one I am using). But now how do I test it so make sure it working as expected?

Comment: jquery trigger? ..for ui testing check selenium

Comment: I have never tried to automate something like this before. All I have done is try to rapidly doubleclick and see if the form was submitted twice. Just looking for a better way. I'll take a look at Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you're testing and what technique do you use. E.g., you can use Selenium to click the button several times. Or, if you're more focused on the server side, use `httpUnit` to submit a form twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would point the form towards a test email or even provide a CC address to test these.  By utilizing what was pointed out in the link, or using preventDefault, it should work just fine